# QR Code on a cardboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a question, I designed a small Cardboard in Adobe illustrator for a client to be hanged on a lanyard/necklace, with dimensions : 6x9cm (width x height), with the 1st cm at the top to be perforated later, same design as the image attached

[image]!

he wants the logo to be put in the middle of the QR Code. now my question is what should be done if he sent me the QR code without a “hole” to place the logo into it, should I put a white square behind the logo or that would affect the reading of code in anyway?
another question is that are there QR Codes with holes or did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a new QR code with the logo in the middle.

Look for a QR Code generator with logo like [this one](https://www.qr-code-generator.com/a1/?ut_source=google_c&ut_medium=cpc&ut_campaign=en_solutions_features&ut_content=qr_code_logo_bmm&ut_term=%2Bqr%20%2Bcodes%20%2Bwith%20%2Blogo_b&gclid=CjwKCAjwq-TmBRBdEiwAaO1en2k9FZ0KwZfz9gJA_W3LrTwJ2J5vUtMf7lQyoBn7yY6QHcMvyZKhuxoCIMMQAvD_BwE)
[image]

Comment: How's that any different from doing it in Illustrator? Kinda surprised OP chose this question given it fails to answer any of OP's questions and concerns.

Comment: Just be careful and confirm your QR actually points to the desired site. Sometimes the "free" and cool QR generators send the traffic to their page first, so you are tied to them in some way. I use this site to confirm the real link inside the QR: https://webqr.com/